# Obtaining output of a symfony command via shell_exec / ApplicationTester etc. in symfony unit test

Tags: symfony, command, phpunit, shell-exec

I'd like to run a command in a separate process  from a unit test and obtain its output. I've tested several options like using `shell_exec` or the `ApplicationTester`-class. While the command is obviously executed (I checked by inserting some side-effects), its output cannot be obtained when executed from the unit test.

However, if I create a small stand-alone php-file (see below, `runDummyCmd.php`) that contains a corresponding `shell_exec`, I obtain the output of the symfony command.

**How to reproduce**

Dummy-Command:

```
<?php


namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class DummyCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:dummycmd')
            ->setDescription('Can be used for testing commands')
            ->setHelp('Does a simple output.');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Test!');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Test-Case:

```
class MyTest extends MyKernelTestCase
{
    protected $projectDir;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->projectDir = static::$container->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
    }

    public function testGetOutputOfCommand() {
        $cmd = 'env APP_ENV=test '. $this->projectDir . '/bin/console app:dummycmd';

        dump($cmd);
        $output = shell_exec($cmd);

        dump($output);
    }
}
```

runDummyCmd.php:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'env APP_ENV=test bin/console app:dummycmd';

var_dump($cmd);
$output = shell_exec($cmd);

var_dump($output);
?>
```

**Outputs**
Output of the unit-test:

```
"env APP_ENV=test PROJECT_DIR/bin/console app:dummycmd"
null
```

Output of the execution of `runDummyCmd.php` on the console:

```
string(41) "env APP_ENV=test bin/console app:dummycmd"
string(6) "Test!
"
```

Comment: If, however, I misspell the command and thus `bin/console` produces an error, the corresponding error messages are passed to the output.

Comment: I dumped your command and test into a new symfony project and it worked straight away. What output do you get when you redirect stderr to stdout (`$cmd = 'env APP_ENV=test '. $this->projectDir . '/bin/console app:dummycmd 2>&1';`)?

Comment: Thanks for your test!
I tried redirecting stderr and it does not work either, the result still is null.

Comment: Strange. The exit code of the execution would be interesting, too. Since you're using symfony anyway, you could run the command using the [process component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). This gives you a convenient way to access stdout, stderr and the exit code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response:
I executed the command using exec() and obtained both the output and the exit code, which is 0. As I wrote in my original question, the command is executed which can be noticed due to its side-effects. It is very strange...

Comment: I did another test:
I executed the file `runDummyCmd.php` from the test, i.e. I indirectly executed the app:dummycmd. And in this script I displayed the exit code and the output of the command. Still, the result is the same: the exit code is 0 but I cannot see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CommandTester class?

```
$command = $application->find('app:dummycmd');
$commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
$commandTester->execute([
   'command'  => $command->getName()
]);
$output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
```

Comment: Yes, I used that before but it does not spawn a child process which is important for me.